# How to create rails restful member routes in javascript/jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

How to create rails restful member routes in javascript/jQuery code ?
Here is scenario where i wanted to add customer javascript variable to rails route

```
:javascript
data += "<li><a href=\"#{edit_customer_path('"+customer.id+"')}\">Edit</a></li>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I had to do the same thing I did next

defined global JS variable

```
var editCustomerPath = "#{edit_customer_path(:id=>'some_unique_vaue')}"
```

and later

```
appropriatePath = editCustomerPath.replace('some_unique_vaue', customer.id)
data += "<li><a href=" + appropriatePath + ">Edit</a></li>"
```